Declare variables with dynamic enum type in scriptable object
I’m writing a scriptable variable for the enum variable and would like it to be dynamic so it works with all enum types from the project.
Meaning as a first step, in inspector, I should be able to select the enum type. Then the other variables like ‘value’ and ‘initial value’ will use this enum type automatically and derive from it.
I fail to declare these variables dynamically. Is this even possible? Using reflection I thought it should. Any idea is welcome.

I assume this is for the Unity Editor. Can you please give more details? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, sorry.

as far as I know, you can't do anything that unity do that automatically.
you can write a custom inspector
